# Outputting a datetime as a unix timestamp using Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, datetime, razor, timestamp

I'm currently outputting a datetime variable using Razor like so:

```
<td>@Html.Raw(Model.Records[i].Incident.DateRecieved)</td>
```

However, I'd like to change this to a timestamp for easier sorting purposes, but can't figure out the best way of doing it. I've tried using the following code:

```
<td>@Model.Records[i].Incident.DateRecieved.ToString("yyyy MM dd")</td>
```

But Visual Studio is saying that there is no overload for ToString that takes 1 arguement.

Any ideas on the best way of doing this please?

Thanks

Comment: What is type of `DateRecieved`? (possibly not `DateTime`, probably some of DB types)

Comment: Hi, it has a datatype of ?DateTime

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems your `DataRecieved` is `Nullable<DateTime>`. Try this, get the actual value first then use `ToString` and pass the datetime format:

```
<td>@Model.Records[i].Incident.DateRecieved.Value.ToString("yyyy MM dd")</td>
```

If your `DateRecieved` is `null` then it will probably throw an exception.In order to avoid this you can use an `if` statement:

```
    <td> @if(Model.Records[i].Incident.DateRecieved != null)
         { <text>@Model.Records[i].Incident.DateRecieved.Value.ToString("yyyy MM dd") </text> }
         else { <text>"default value"</text> }
    </td>
```

Comment: Thank you very much, unfortunately now I get an error saying "Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Nullable object must have a value." though

Comment: @Nick if there is no value in it, what do you want to display ?

Comment: Just a blank space I guess, if that's possible? :) Thank you

Comment: Thank you very much! I've changed the else statement to else { Html.Raw("default value"); } because it was generating an error before, but it's not actually outputting any HTML even if these is a value. I've wrapped the second line in Html.Raw too with no joy unfortunately

Comment: it seems I messed up the razor syntax :)) try again with `text` tags.